# How is the performance on BitBucket Data Center?

Tags: bitbucket, git-stash, bitbucket-server

I am running my stash application on single node. The plan is to upgrade it to BitBucket and push it to DataCenter. So with this multi-node architecture, I wanted to know the impact of performance. Is it much better compared to single node architecture?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is about the same. Data Centre uses NFS to provide HA Active-Active capability so. NFS speeds can vary:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/bitbucket-data-center-faq-776663707.html#BitbucketDataCenterFAQ-nfsWon'tNFSbethebottleneckinmyBitbucketDataCenterinstance?

The main advantage of Data Centre is mirroring if you have remote developers:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/smart-mirroring-776640046.html

High availability:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/high-availability-for-bitbucket-server-776640137.html

It is also easy to add more nodes to a cluster should one go down:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/clustering-with-bitbucket-data-center-776640164.html

See also:

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/jira-software/server-vs-data-center-whats-right

https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/bitbucket-data-center-performance-668468334.html

Comment: Thanks. These are helpful.